# how to set QTimer in nanoseconds

Tags: qt, qtimer

Is it possible to set timer value as we earlier set in linux

> struct timespec intervalTime;
>       long seconds,nanoSeconds;
>       seconds         = 0;
>       nanoSeconds = 100000;
>
> ```
> intervalTime.tv_sec  = seconds;
> intervalTime.tv_nsec = nanoSeconds;
> ```

is it possible for me to set the same time in Qt of QTimer

QTimer::setValue( 1 millisec)  , how can i set for nanoseconds ..

please help ,
Thx in advance

Comment: try to read http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/5421-high-resolution-timer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nanoseconds - no, but if you set the timer type to Qt::PreciseTimer you can get millisecond accuracy